# Converging or diverging series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine if the series $\left(\frac{\:n+3}{2n+1}\right)^{\ln(n)}$ diverges or converges.

I've tried both the root and ratio tests which got me nowhere.

I tried finding a smaller divergent series (or bigger convergent series) to apply the comparison test but failed.

Any hints or advices are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to apply the integral test?

Comment: yes , however the series shouldn't the series be decreasing and positive? isn't it increasing for $n <4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\left(\frac{n+3}{2n+1}\right)^{\log(n)}=n^{\log\left(\frac{n+3}{2n+1}\right)}\ge n^{-\log(2)}$$

and $\log(2)<1$.

Now apply the comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\left(\frac{n+3}{2n+1}\right)^{\ln(n)}=e^{\ln n \cdot \ln\left(\frac{n+3}{2n+1}\right)}\sim e^{\ln n \cdot \ln \frac12}=e^{\ln n^{-\ln 2}}=\frac1{n^{\ln 2}} $$

then refer to direct comparison test or limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n}$.

Comment: How is $\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)\sim \frac12$?

Comment: @MarkViola opssss...I lost a log! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As $n\to \infty, \frac{n+3}{n}\to1$ and $\frac{2n+1}{2n}\to 1$

so:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n+3}{2n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n}{2n}}=\frac 12$$
Also note that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln(n)}=\infty$$ so we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg(\frac 12\bigg)^n}=0$$

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the series.

Comment: Well, I have shown that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{n+3}{2n+1}\bigg)^{\ln(n)}}\approx\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^{-n}}$$

Comment: But the series diverges.